# Real Time Input Reading in Python?

Tags: python, input

I am making an adventure game that requires acceptance of input without the user having to press "return" to send that input. 
My problem is: 
    usr_inp = input("enter something:")
    # do something with usr input

How do I do something with the user input AS SOON AS something is typed on the keyboard?

Comment: If you are using windows, you can check out [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html)

Comment: I'm using Mac sorry

Comment: search `getchar()` - ie. module [getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/),